# Blue and red sculpting tools not responding at all

Tags: sculpting

It works, then it doesn't work. And I have no idea what it needs to get working.

I can't use anything with the multires modifier on. I tried subdivide modifier and applied it, but still nothing.

Grab tool works. The clay tool barely works like someone who only does the minimum job after he gets pushed to do what he's supposed to do. All other blue tools are MIA.

It is very frustrating. Does anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day wasted yesterday, I made my laptop shut down for the night which I haven't done in months (I usually make it sleep). Today, the sculpting tools are all back in business. I don't know if shutting it down had to do with it, but it works now.